# SQL Agent Jobs Automatically Disabled After Modifying Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, maintenance-plans

I modified a maintenance plan yesterday, to find out this morning (by using the last modified date from sysjobs) that all jobs related to the maintenance plan are disabled.

I can't figure out why this may be. The SQL Job Owner is `sa` and I merely changed a maintenance clean-up task with the maintenance plan and saved the job.

Comment: Did you check the time of those disabled jobs? were they disabled during same time when modifications were done on maintenance task?

Comment: Hi - Yes I have. There were 5 jobs all linked to the maintenance plan which were all disabled within half a second at around the same time I was making changes to the maintenance plan.

Comment: Ok, so when changes were made and you saved the job, did you see the owner of those jobs attached to that common modified maintenance plan getting changed to some default ?

Comment: Nope - The job owner is sa which would not be the account which originally set up the maintenance plan. I've been able to replicate the issue and its only when I save the maintenance plan remotely from SSMS 2012 the issue occurs. If I log onto the box and use SSMS 2005 the jobs are not disabled - odd!

Comment: I believe you are logged in with sa when trying to modify the job, so when you save the job, it takes the account logged in when you are taking remotely. so since owner got changed and since sa account would have been disabled the job shows disable. However when you log onto the box, it would not be sa, so jobs didnt got disabled.

Comment: Nope I'm logged in with the same account. We use domain accounts only and the sa account is for emergency use only. I also changed the owner on the job, saved the maintenance plan and the owner didn't change.

Comment: Can you try changing the owner of the maintenance plan as you said you change the  owner of the job ?

Comment: @Kapil if SA is owner of the job and is disabled this wont force Job to become disabled. Please note when SA is owner of job no impersonation happens so even if SA is disabled job would run. Its strange why jobs become disabled I would only comment further if I am able to reproduce this issue

Answer (score 3):

You haven't done anything wrong or gone crazy - it's a known bug and we've experienced the same thing.

Our process was changed that we would script out job status and reapply after any maintenance plan work - until we could move off of maintenance plans entirely (which we did).

Continuing on from the comments on the main question, there is an owner associated with the package itself which then gets copied over to the jobs and there's no UI to change it (you can modify it directly in the MSDB package tables though!)

We remediated that later on but I am unaware if there's a link between that referenced login disappearing and the jobs being disabled. It's possible.